# $set not creating filed if it does not exists during update mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

in the user manual I could see the behavior for update $set

If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.

If you specify multiple field-value pairs, $set will update or create each field.

I am executing following

```
db.cachedNodeChassis.update(
{
         "deviceIp":"10.115.75.77",
          "chassis.ports.1/1/x10.portId":"1/1/x13"
},
{ 
  "$set": { "chassis.ports.1/1/x13.healthState" : "Red" }
}
)
```

o/p:
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

which is supposed to create healthState columns in the ports embedded document I hope ,can some one please clarify.

Comment: If it "does not exist" then the query cannot match it. Remove the field test from the query and just match the document. I also note your "update" references a different "path" from what you are querying. Looks like "typos" as well as the general misundertanding. And the "nModified" as `0` means that the element is already present with the same value that you are trying to update when paired with "nMatched": `1`

Comment: Thanks Steve,I have checked again the above syntax is correct and it went file ,I didnt refreshed the mongoclient.Thanks!!